# After updating to Joomla3.4 version new module is not saving for isis template

Tags: module, templates, joomla-3.4

I am using latest version of joomla 3.4.1, but facing one problem is that when i create new module from joomla administrator module manger and selecting custom html after saving that module its not showing in the module list or if i want to rename my already created module name not showing renamed title name but when i switch to hathor template all the functionality works properly why it is not working for isis template don't know is there any settings from joomla 3.4  admin please suggest some solution.

Comment: problem is solved by increase max_input_vars = 3000 in php.ini administrator file.

Comment: @paypal, please add this as a proper answer and accept it by clicking the "tick" icon, so people can see it has been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common pitfall to forget some filter.

Try to Clear all Module Manager filters and sort by ID desc to find the latest inserted module.

Comment: thanks @anibal cleared all module manger filter and sorted in descending order by id still not getting latest added module

Comment: Try to add a new one.

Comment: Onsaving custom module save button work as save and close... is there any js conflicting issue.

Comment: while i changing my admin template to hathor it worked properly why it is not working for isisi template..